# Как сделать откат последней операции в T-sql

Tags: sql, база-данных, sql-server

Возможно ли сделать откат последней операции в T-Sql?

Comment: Да, если перед началом операции вы открыли транзакцию, то откатить все до ее начала можно с помощью rollback

Answer (score 2):

Если транзакция ещё не зафиксирована, откатить её можно при помощи стандартного оператора `ROLLBACK`. Для транзакций которые уже зафиксированы, откат в "ручном" режиме не поддерживается. Только восстановление из резервной копии.